# wp7.5 Mango Tiles

Tags: windows-phone-7

Mango tiles have two sides. Tiles flip automatically to show 2 sides. I want to know whether it is possible to configure the flipping time ? also I want to know whether it is possible to show one side of the tile for 5 seconds and the other side of the tile only for 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time between flips of LiveTiles and the length of time that the back is shown varies and is deliberately nondeterministic. This is to ensure a consistency of behaviour across all pinned tiles and to keep the start screen visually engaging. It also stops tiles flipping in a consitent way relative to each other.

Answer (score -2):

[VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) can help you proceed in the right direction. You can freeze and unfreeze/expand the visual state of the live tile with VisualStateManager class.

Comment: really? a live tile isn't a Silverlight control.

Comment: My bad. Mixed it up with Hub Tiles.